# Is this the correct behavior of a ObservableCollection and Linq?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, observablecollection

Hi I just ran into a sync problem, and have replicated it in this small example.

```
class MyClass
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>
                           {
                               new MyClass() {Number = 1},
                               new MyClass() {Number = 2},
                               new MyClass() {Number = 3}
                           };

            var count = from i in list where i.Number == 1 select i;
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", count.Count());

            list[2].Number = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", count.Count());
        }
```

This will output

```
Found 1
Found 2
```

This is not what I expected, would have guessed it would return 1 both times.
It there anyway to avoid this action and still use a observable collection?

I'm trying to implement a method to reorder, but this makes it hard to select the correct item.

## UPDATE

An easy solution would of cource be to modify it like this

```
int found = count.Count();
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", found);

            list[2].Number = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", found);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the lazy evaluation of your LINQ query and has nothing to do with the `ObservableCollection`. If you change your LINQ query to the following line:

```
(from i in list where i.Number == 1 select i).ToList();
```

you will see the behavior you expect.

The `ToList()` addition makes sure your LINQ query is evaluated at that moment. Otherwise, it is evaluated only when necessary. Because you call `Count()` twice, the query is evaluated twice but on different data.

Answer (score 2):

You encountered one of the pitfalls of LINQ. The variable `count` in your example isn't the **result** of a query, it **is** the query. Every time you change something in the underlying collection, the change will be reflected in subsequent calls.